# How to change h2 to h3 products in woocommerce home page?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I was looking for change the h2 of my products in the homepage of my website into h3 and i found this snippet :

```
remove_action( 'woocommerce_shop_loop_item_title','woocommerce_template_loop_product_title', 10 );
add_action('woocommerce_shop_loop_item_title', 'abChangeProductsTitle', 10 );
function abChangeProductsTitle() {
echo '<h3 class="woocommerce-loop-product_title">' . get_the_title() . '</h3>';
}
```

The thing is that it add a h3 to my products but it don't delete the h2 ones. I have now both headings and i am looking for delete h2 of my products in the store front.

As you can guess I am beggining with coding but I presume that it's probably due to the first line, i did research about how I can fix it but i found nothing.

Do you have any solution ? Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

One of the ways to achieve this easily is using a child theme (which I hope you are).

1. In your child theme, copy the WooCommerce file you want to change the H2 tag to H3. make sure in your child theme you follow the exact directory structure as in the WooCommerce directory.
2. Once you have moved the file, simply change the H2 tag to H3 using your favourite editor.

The solution above gets the work done.
One issue you might face sometime in the future is when WooCommerce makes a major update to their plugin. You will need to then

1. Update WooCommerce
2. Migrate the new template into the child theme

However, whenever there is a major update, WordPress will alert you on the outdated files in your child theme that need to be updated.

In a nutshell, as long as you are regularly maintaining your site, this solution works perfectly and you do not need to figure out which hooks to use.